# Problem with \hbox inside list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

In the example below, the first `\hbox to \linewidth` ends up at the left of the page, despite the fact that it is inside an `itemize` environment. The presence of `\hspace*{0pt}` before the second seems to eliminate the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This is some text which shows the width of the whole page.
We must make sure it is long enough to occupy at least one whole line.
\begin{itemize}
\item 
Inside the itemize environment, the text is not so wide. 
\par
\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\par
\hspace*{0pt}\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `\par` is special inside a list. Using `\endgraf` you'll notice a different output than you see with using `\par`.

Comment: `\hbox` is not a supported LaTeX command: you are supposed to use `\makebox`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\hbox` is not a supported LaTeX command: you are supposed to use `\makebox` or in this case just `\rule` directly. (Note similarly that while the LaTeX  `\rule` works the TeX primitive `\hrule` would fail in the same way as `\hbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
This is some text which shows the width of the whole page.
We must make sure it is long enough to occupy at least one whole line.
\begin{itemize}
\item 
Inside the itemize environment, the text is not so wide. 
\par
\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\par
\hspace*{0pt}\hbox to \linewidth{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\par
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\par
\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

Technically what is going wrong is that LaTeX lists produce indentation by adjusting the paragraph shape, but `\hbox` does not start a paragraph it adds itself directly to the current vertical or horizontal list, with the result you see.

Comment: In the actual application I need implicit braces and `\makebox[\linewidth]\bgroup stuff \egroup` fails. Any ideas?

Comment: well I could tell you to use an environment form but if no one is looking I could tell you to put `\leavevmode` in front of the `\hbox`. If you compare the definitions of `\mbox` and `\hbox` you'll see that is the main difference. Of course `\leavevmode` isn't a supported LaTeX command either, but sometimes two wrongs do make a right.